# Produces a string based on rules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was recently playing around with some code, and someone mentioned that my code uses too many classes. I didn't realize I've been doing ES6 incorrectly for so long.

I'm having a hard time finding a way to organize my code in a way that reads nicely. I say this coming from a C# background.

Thanks for your time, everyone.

```
class Producer {
    constructor(starterString) {
        this.rules = [];
        this.createRules();
        this.producedString = starterString;
    }
    createRules() {
        this.rules.add(new RuleAddE());
        this.rules.add(new RuleAddNumberOne());
    }
    produce() {
        for(var i = 0, len = this.rules.length; i < len; i++) {
            this.producedString = this.rules[i].run(this.producedString);
        }

        return this.producedString;
    }
}

class Rule {
    constructor() {
        this.applied = false;
    }
    run() {            
    }
}

class RuleAddE extends Rule {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    run(stringToChange) {
        this.applied = true;
        return stringToChange + "e";
    }
}

class RuleAddNumberOne extends Rule {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    run(stringToChange) {
        this.applied = true;
        return stringToChange + "1";
    }
}

var producer = new Producer("aa 1hdheb");

console.log(producer.produce());
```

How could I improve this code with more proper structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1**. You have classes but you do not effectively *need* them because they do not keep any state (even the `applied` field is actually unused). In C# you do not have much options (unless they're local) but in JavaScript you can use functions anywhere:

```
const ruleAddE = (text) => text + "E";
const ruleAddNumberOne = (text) => text + "1";
```

And so on. Now let's go to the *core* of your algorithm: the `Producer` class. Do you need e class here? From the code you posted it seems you don't and again a function is enough. Let me assume that `rules` is accessed from outside the class then it makes sense to keep it in-place.

`constructor`. I'm not sure if you want to discard `starterString`, repeately calling `produce()` will always work on latest *produced* string. If this is the intended behavior then you can let it as-is.

`createRules`. If this is a *private* method I like to prefix it with `_`. It's not a rule, not everyone agrees with this and - unlike Python - it does not change method visibility/accessibility. I like it because it's self-documenting and I won't, by chance, use externally a private method (which is an implementation detail). You do not even really need this function because code is reduced to:

```
this.rules = [ ruleAddE, ruleAddNumberOne ];
```

Note that your original code is broken because there isn't a method `Array.add()` but `Array.push()`.

`produce`. This may be simplified, the same way you'd do in C# using some LINQ:

```
produce() {
    this.producedString = this
        .rules.reduce((text, rule) => rule(text), this.producedString);

    return this.producedString;
}
```

---

**2**. In short, your code might be:

```
const ruleAddE = (text) => text + "E";
const ruleAddNumberOne = (text) => text + "1";

class Producer {
    constructor(starterString) {
        this.producedString = starterString;
        this.rules = [ ruleAddE, ruleAddNumberOne ];
    }

    produce() {
        this.producedString = this.rules
            .reduce((text, rule) => rule(text), this.producedString);

        return this.producedString;
    }
}
```

---

Note that for `undefined` and `null` inputs the result is pretty odd (`undefined` is converted to a literal string) while you may expect an empty string in this case. If that's your case then change declaration to:

```
this.producedString = starterString || "";
```

We're not using `Rule` class hierarchy but, in general, remember that in JavaScript there isn't a (easy) syntax to enforce an object with a specific base class then, unless, it adds something, you can simply drop it.

---

**3**. To answer the question about "do you need a class for `Producer`?": if you don't need to call `produce()` multiple times on the same object then you don't even need a class and everything may be reduced to:

```
const ruleAddE = (text) => text + "E";
const ruleAddNumberOne = (text) => text + "1";

function produce(starterString) {
    const rules = [ ruleAddE, ruleAddNumberOne ];
    return rules.reduce((text, rule) => rule(text), starterString);
}
```

In general in JavaScript you can use classes when you want to carry state and behavior on the same object but for everything else you may well use plain functions (and if you use modules you do not even need to use classes as *namespaces*).

**4**. If you're using a class only to give a chance to the caller to specify a different set of rules:

```
function produce(starterString, rules = [ ruleAddE, ruleAddNumberOne ]) {
    return rules.reduce((text, rule) => rule(text), starterString || "");
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for going in depth. I think you make really good points, and I definitely overused classes. I also don't need a class for Producer, and I very much like your way of doing it. I think I got caught up in thinking that separating out everything into classes makes code more readable. But I think yours is perfectly clear, with a lot less "fluff". Also, I can't upvote you yet, but I will definitely do so when I have enough points!

Comment: @Feign I have a C# background then I understand your problem, in JS I often have to stop and _remember_ that things are different. Functions (like in many other languages like F#, Python or C++) are first-class citizens and we do not need to wrap everything in a class.

Comment: I think that's a really valuable lesson I had not learned yet.